# Error al utilizar ciclo for en entity framework

Tags: sql, entity-framework, linq

Estoy realizando una búsqueda de datos específicos y actualización de un campo en especial, para ello hice esto:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("api/Actualizacion/BusquedaActualizacion")]
public IEnumerable BusquedaActualizacion() {
  using(ProductoTerminadoContext bd = new ProductoTerminadoContext()) {

    List < int > listOfRegistros = new List < int > ();

    var listaIds = (from b in bd.OrdenesPt where b.Ot.Trim().Equals("") && b.Pedido.Trim().Equals("") && b.Posicion.Equals(0) && b.CveCompuesta == null select new {
      Id = b.Id
    }).ToArray();

    var cantidadRegistos = listaIds.Length - 1;
    if (listaIds.Length > 0) {
      for (int i = 0; i <= cantidadRegistos; i++) {
        listOfRegistros.Add(listaIds[i].Id);
      }

      for (int i = 0; i <= cantidadRegistos; i++) {

        var actualizacion = (from b in bd.OrdenesPt where b.Id.Equals(listOfRegistros.ElementAt(i)) select b).First();
        actualizacion.CveCompuesta = "0" + listOfRegistros.ElementAt(i);

      }
      bd.SaveChanges();
      yield
      return 1;
    } else {
      yield
      return 0;
    }

  }
}
```

En la cual primero hago la búsqueda de los Id's que cumplan con la evaluación:

```
var listaIds = (from b in bd.OrdenesPt where b.Ot.Trim().Equals("") && b.Pedido.Trim().Equals("") && b.Posicion.Equals(0) && b.CveCompuesta == null select new {
      Id = b.Id
    }).ToArray();
```

Dependiendo de de la cantidad de registros evaluo para poder agregar los resultados a la lista definida al inicio:

```
if (listaIds.Length > 0) {
      for (int i = 0; i <= cantidadRegistos; i++) {
        listOfRegistros.Add(listaIds[i].Id);
      }
}
```

si imprimo el array salen la lista esperada sin ningún problema luego de eso hice la actualización  así:

```
    for (int i = 0; i <= cantidadRegistos; i++) {
    
            var actualizacion = (from b in bd.OrdenesPt where b.Id.Equals(listOfRegistros.ElementAt(i)) select b).First();
            actualizacion.CveCompuesta = "0" + listOfRegistros.ElementAt(i);
    
   }
   bd.SaveChanges();
```

Me marcan el siguiente error y me redirige a un link

> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateConcurrencyException: Database
> operation expected to affect 1 row(s) but actually affected 3 row(s).
> Data may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded. See
> http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=527962 for information on
> understanding and handling optimistic concurrency exceptions.    at
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.AffectedCountModificationCommandBatch.ThrowAggregateUpdateConcurrencyException(Int32
> commandIndex, Int32 expectedRowsAffected, Int32 rowsAffected)    at
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.AffectedCountModificationCommandBatch.ConsumeResultSetWithoutPropagation(Int32
> commandIndex, RelationalDataReader reader)

Entonces si captura los datos, más sin embargo sigue sin poder actualizarlo

**ACTUALIZACIÓN**

Con el la primer búsqueda, deseo encontrar los Id's que cumplen con la condición dicha, que es esta:

```
List<int> listOfRegistros = new List<int>();
                var listaIds = (from b in bd.OrdenesPt
                                where b.Posicion.Equals(0) && b.CveCompuesta == null
                                select new
                                {
                                    Id = b.Id
                                }).ToArray();
```

En este caso me resuelve los siguientes números : `[169,170,171]` entonces lo que hago es una vez obtenido los **ids** hice una prueba tratar de retornar los valores que se obtenían deacuerdo a la lista devuelta de **listaIds** y me devuelve lo siguiente:

```
[{
    "ot": "xxxx",
    "pedido": "xxxx",
    "posicion": 0,
    "sociedad": "xxxx",
    "numero_Cliente": "          ",
    "cliente": "                                   ",
    "codigoMaterial": "xxxxx",
    "material": "xxxxxx",
    "cantidad": 1,
    "importe": xxxx,
    "fecha": "xxxx",
    "salida": null,
    "salidaEmp": null,
    "fechaSalidaEmp": "1900-01-01T00:00:00",
    "mes": "xx",
    "ejercicio": "xx",
    "cveCompuesta": null,
    "id": 169
  },
  {
    "ot": "xxxx",
    "pedido": "xxxx",
    "posicion": 0,
    "sociedad": "xxxx",
    "numero_Cliente": "          ",
    "cliente": "                                   ",
    "codigoMaterial": "xxxxx",
    "material": "xxxxxx",
    "cantidad": 1,
    "importe": xxxx,
    "fecha": "xxxx",
    "salida": null,
    "salidaEmp": null,
    "fechaSalidaEmp": "1900-01-01T00:00:00",
    "mes": "xx",
    "ejercicio": "xx",
    "cveCompuesta": null,
    "id": 169
  },
  {
    "ot": "xxxx",
    "pedido": "xxxx",
    "posicion": 0,
    "sociedad": "xxxx",
    "numero_Cliente": "          ",
    "cliente": "                                   ",
    "codigoMaterial": "xxxxx",
    "material": "xxxxxx",
    "cantidad": 1,
    "importe": xxxx,
    "fecha": "xxxx",
    "salida": null,
    "salidaEmp": null,
    "fechaSalidaEmp": "1900-01-01T00:00:00",
    "mes": "xx",
    "ejercicio": "xx",
    "cveCompuesta": null,
    "id": 169
  },
]
```

me esta devolviendo la misma respuesta 3 veces

Comment: no termino de entender que trataste de hacer.. porque esto devuelve un ienumerable? que va a enumerar, si siempre actualiza todo.. que quisiste hacer con el codigo???? me parece que el problema viene por ahi...

Comment: Lo que deseo es que con los datos provenientes de **var listaIds**,  un ejemplo si vienen 1,2,3 que ese resultado en la siguiente instruccion los tome en el ciclo for y en cada registro el campo **actualizacion.CveCompuesta** se actualice dependiendo de la lista que se genere en **listaIds**

Comment: pero el yield retorna inmediatamente y guarda el estado para la proxima llamada a la funcion de iteracion.. creo que tu problema esta en otro lado...

Comment: el error esta desde la consulta y sigo sin poder resolverlo

Comment: porque haces un yield return?

Comment: y porque un metodo get de una api devuelve un ienumerable.. creo que esas cosas, hacen que EF llegue a este metodo en un estado no valido y ahi se genera el problema...

Comment: @gbianchi ya actualice mi pregunta con el error